# Reference Plupload through middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, plupload

I am trying to inject middle ware and load pl upload through that. Below are the packages I am trying to integrate inside my application.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/plupload

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-plupload

I am getting below error. I tried reinstall packages and run however no luck.

Need suggestion if I am missing anything.

```
ReferenceError: Image is not defined
    at .....\node_modules\plupload\js\plupload.full.min.js:13:12305
    at .....\node_modules\plupload\js\plupload.full.min.js:13:12504
    at .....\node_modules\plupload\js\plupload.full.min.js:13:13299
    at .....\node_modules\plupload\js\plupload.full.min.js:13:709
    at i (.....\node_modules\plupload\js\plupload.full.min.js:13:402)
    at n (.....\node_modules\plupload\js\plupload.full.min.js:13:687)
    at .....\node_modules\plupload\js\plupload.full.min.js:13:5378
    at Object.<anonymous> (.....\node_modules\plupload\js\plupload.full.min.js:16:11339)
    at i (.....\node_modules\plupload\js\plupload.full.min.js:13:51)
    at i (.....\node_modules\plupload\js\plupload.full.min.js:13:193)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.....\node_modules\plupload\js\plupload.full.min.js:13:209)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Module._compile (.....\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (.....\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
```

UPDATE -

Just to give more code insight, Below is the code

```
import {createMiddleware as createUploaderMiddleware} from 'redux-plupload';
import plupload from 'plupload';


const uploadDocmentMiddleware = (config) => (store) => (next) => (action) => {
      // For now just returning some value
      return true;
};

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    const uploaderMiddleware = createUploaderMiddleware(plupload, {
        uploadDocmentMiddleware
    });

    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        // Initiate redux dev tools
        composeWithDevTools(
            applyMiddleware(
                FirstMiddleware(config),
                SecondMiddleware(config),
                ...
                .....
                // middle ware for pl upload
                uploaderMiddleware(config),
                typeof window !== 'undefined' && reduxImmutableStateInvariant()
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Just curious will this happen if react express application??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you!

We figured out, seems due to server rendering it breaks to load Pl upload and moxie.

We do not have any workaround yet for same. :(

Thanks though.